# Show excerpt at top of post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a js quiz template that is used for multiple quizzes, and I'd like each one to show that post's excerpt. I tried adding `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` at the top of the template, but that shows just the excerpt with a "click to read more" button. Is there a way to call the excerpt for a post without "read more" and with content after it?

http://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/quiz/

```
<?php
/*
Single Post Template: Quiz
*/

get_header(); 

?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 content-area" role="main">
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
<h2>French Quiz</h2>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>"></script>
<div id="quiz">

<form id="quiz-form">

</form>

</div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `get_the_excerpt()` instead:

```
$my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
echo $my_excerpt;
```

There is more on this at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

**EDIT:**

This, like all post functions, need to be called in the loop:

```
<?php
global $more; $more = -1; // suppress the more tag
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        echo $my_excerpt;
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Comment: `get_the_excerpt()` must be used within the Loop. He's calling it outside of the Loop.

Comment: That's a lot better, thank you, but it still has the "click to read" button.

Comment: You can customize that text: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_The_Read_More_Link_Text

Comment: But it is working outside of the loop, right where I originally had '<?php the_excerpt(); ?>'

Comment: @lkl - it may be working for the first post, but I can't see how it would work for more than 1 post. Either way, doing things in the loop is good practice when dealing with posts =)

Comment: Understood. :-)  But with the new code it's not working - the excerpt is repeating a million times and crashing FF.